# Knowledge articles are not visible in Customer Community Portal template to the community user

Tags: community, lightning-knowledge

The license used is Customer Community Plus and Profile used is Customer Community Plus User. On Profile level all the necessary permissions are given Read on Knowledge object and General User Permissions - Manage Articles and Knowledge Tab is Default On. But still the community user is not able to view the knowledge article in community after login.

The admin can view the article in community.

On Article level, Visible to Customer is marked TRUE and published.

External OWD for Knowledge is set to Private, but the user is given all the necessary permissions at profile level.

I have tried everything mentioned in the salesforce documentation but not able to achieve the
PS: "Allow View Knowledge" permission is not available for the Customer Community Plus license profiles. Not sure if this is the main reason.

Comment: What [sharing model](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_sharing_setup.htm&type=5) are you using for Knowledge? Standard Salesforce sharing model or data categories? It sounds like a sharing issue, but would need more info from the help doc I shared.

Comment: I used the standard salesforce sharing model which we can select from the knowledge setting page. But, it didn't work for me even after doing all the required things as mentioned above. I have also enabled Data Categories and tried to tag the articles with the data category and then tag the articles with a topic in community but no success.

Comment: Do you have sharing rules set up to give the community user access to the article? Saying you did all the required things mentioned above is not the same as telling us exactly what specifics you did as sometimes it's the little things that are missed when it comes to setup things like this.